# mysql ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql

i have installed mysql 8.0.12 into one linux node and when i try to give below grant permission to get access from other nodes, i am getting 42000 error

command issued :

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Return results:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'secure1t'' at line 1

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya That's wrong. Backticks are for database/table/column names.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You don't use `IDENTIFIED BY` in `GRANT` queries, it's used in `CREATE USER`.

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';
```

[GRANT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html) command reference

[CREATE USER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-user.html) command reference

Comment: Odd. The questioner's command worked on mysql on debian, but not on my mac. Both are v8. Any idea why?

Comment: +1 upvote @Magnus - check the minor release in that v8 release - my guess is that they could be different, as this answer seems to suggest https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/274460/6090

Comment: mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'yogi'@'%';
ERROR 1410 (42000): You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT

Comment: Did you first do `CREATE USER yogi@%`?

Answer (score 2):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON your_desired_database_name.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
```

then

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

**This worked for me and will work for you
**

Comment: You don't need to use `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` after `GRANT`. It's only needed when you make changes directly to the tables that hold privilege instead of using `GRANT`.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

modify bind address to

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Afer that connect to your my sql console

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
create user  'user'@'%' identified by 'password';
grant all on *.* to  'user'@'%';
exit;
```

Then restart the mysql server

```
sudo systemctl restart mysql
```

Note: i actually had issues updating a user so i created a new user for remote connection which would have all the permission